# UIScrollView inside UIPageViewController: 1 and 2 finger swipe gestures

Tags: ios

**Structure**:
I have one UIPageViewController, currently containing two `UIViewController` (called e.g. `MenuVC` and `ImageScrollVC`).
In the second UIViewController (the `ImageScrollVC`) I have a `UIScrollView`. This UIScrollView contains multiple images. The user should be able to swipe between the images.

**I want**:

- The `UIPageViewController` should only scroll when the user is using *two* fingers.
  ** So the user can swipe between the 'MenuVC' and the `ImageScrollVC` with two fingers, anytime.
- The `UIScrollView` should only scroll when the user is using one finger.
  ** With the one finger swipe gesture the user can change the images.

Is this possible?

My assumption is to forward a two finger swipe gesture to the underlying `UIPageViewController`, but I don't know how to do this.

**Update**:

My ViewController structure:

`RootViewController` is implementing the UIPageViewController (exactly like the Apple template).
`MenuViewController`is the first ViewController in the PageViewController and `ImageScrollViewController` the second one with the UIScrollView for the images.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. It feels that the solution is not the best or nicest one, but it works.

What I did: 
I created a new `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and added it to the `imageScrollView`. This gestureRecognizer has min. and max. touches to 2. In the action method of this recognizer I enabled and disabled scrolling of the imageScrollView.

Also I created a own subclass of `UIScrollView` and implemented the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` to return `YES`.

**In code**:

**`MenuViewController`**: My first UIViewController in the pageVC. The class is doing nothing (for the purpose of this problem). This is only a placeholder to swipe with two fingers and have something to show.

**`RootViewController`**:

```
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
//... exactly the same code as in the Apple template

//the UIPageViewController should only use 2 finger:
for (UIView* view in [self.pageViewController.view subviews]) {
    if ([view  isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        UIScrollView* scrollView = (UIScrollView*)view;
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    }
}
```

**`ImageScrollViewController`**:

```
//self.scrollView is from type 'CustomScrollView'
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // autolayout would be nicer, but this was faster and easier for me
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * _pageImages.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
  //... a for loop to add all UIImageViews as a subView to self.scrollView

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
  twoFingerPan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
  twoFingerPan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
  [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPan];
  twoFingerPan.delegate = (CarScrollView*)self.scrollView;
}

//the inner scrollView for the images should not scroll when two fingers are active
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
  switch (recognizer.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
    case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        break;

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

**`CustomScrollView`**: I created a subclass for the UIScrollView with the images.

```
@interface CarScrollView : UIScrollView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@implementation CarScrollView

//Method has to return YES so that a two finger pan gesture will be used for the outer scrollView/pageViewController
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right on.  Normally your `UIScrollView` in the nested `ImageScrollVC` will handle both one- and two-finger swipes.  You can use a custom subclass of `UIScrollView` in your `ImageScrollVC` to ignore two-finger swipes so that they will continue up the chain and be handled by the `UIPageViewController`.  For more details, check out this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325288/72), from which the sample code below is based.

The gist of it is that you'll implement `-gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` in your `UIScrollView` subclass; only return `YES` if the superclass returns `YES`, and if the number of touches is 1.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    return recognizer.numberOfTouches == 1 && [super gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:recognizer];
}
```

Comment: This is not working. UIPageViewController is not scrolling. I've updated my question with a picture of my viewController and view structure.